# Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 Click on Find in All Files Result Doesn't Open it in an Editor

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 on Windows 10. After I do a "Find in Files" and click "find all", I see all the results in a result panel. The problem is that when I double click on each result, it does nothing and doesn't open it in an editor just as what VS Code does.

I tried reinstalling and it didn't help. What am I missing here? Does anyone know how to make it so that when I double click on the search results, they open up in a code editor?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Double-Clicking-on-a-Find-All-Result-Doe/10118592